# Unity - problem with arms rotation and flip, body flip and shotting - 2d shooter

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, flip

I'm starting out with a small shooting game but I have a problem with my character. The arms have to rotate 360º but the body only right or left (depending on where the rotation of the arms by the mouse).

What I got so far is what you see in the video below but I have two big problems and with the help of tutorials.

- I was able to rotate and flip my arms but not the body.
- Also, when it fires to the right the bullets exit correctly from the firepoint that I created but after the arms flip to the left the bullets (and the weapon fire) are no longer aligned.

**Is this approach that I have tried is not the best for this problem?**

I appreciate your help.

Game link: https://vimeo.com/310853740

Here my arm rotation script:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArmRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    SpriteRenderer spriteRend;

    void Awake()
    {
        spriteRend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        AimArmAtMouse();
    }

    void AimArmAtMouse()
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);  
        Vector2 armToMouse = mousePosition - (Vector2)transform.position;
        float rotationZ = Vector2.SignedAngle(transform.right, armToMouse);  
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, rotationZ);  
        FlipArm(Vector2.SignedAngle(transform.right, Vector2.right));
    }

    void FlipArm(float rotation)
    {
        if (rotation < -90f || rotation > 90f)
        {
            spriteRend.flipY = true;
        }
        else
        {
            spriteRend.flipY = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't flip the firepoint when you flip the sprite. [image] I re-wrote you script to include a reference to the firepoint. I also added a 'FlipFirePoint' function which gets called by your 'FlipArm' function. It should fix your alignment issue.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ArmRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
SpriteRenderer spriteRend;
public Transform firePoint;

void Awake()
{
    spriteRend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void Update()
{
    AimArmAtMouse();
}

void AimArmAtMouse()
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector2 armToMouse = mousePosition - (Vector2)transform.position;
    float rotationZ = Vector2.SignedAngle(transform.right, armToMouse);
    transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, rotationZ);
    FlipArm(Vector2.SignedAngle(transform.right, Vector2.right));
}

void FlipArm(float rotation)
{
    if (rotation < -90f || rotation > 90f)
    {
        spriteRend.flipY = true;
        FlipFirePoint(true);
    }
    else
    {
        spriteRend.flipY = false;
        FlipFirePoint(false);
    }
}

void FlipFirePoint(bool flip)
{
    var pos = firePoint.localPosition;
    pos.x = Mathf.Abs(pos.x) * (flip ? -1 : 1);
    firePoint.localPosition = pos;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sean. I applied the code with your modifications and now i get this: https://ibb.co/42mnSQ7. It's flipping but not around the gun point. What i'm missing??

Comment: @tigrev In the FlipFirePoint function, replace `pos.x = Mathf.Abs(pos.x) * (flip ? -1 : 1);` with `pos.y = Mathf.Abs(pos.y) * (flip ? -1 : 1);`

Comment: Yep,@Sean. That's it! Now it's working perfectly. :) Thank you again! Do you think i can use the same method to make the main body flip to the other side, when the arms flip, without pointing and rotating to the mouse?

Comment: @tigrev I'm glad it's working :) If the arm is a child of the main body, then you can just access its parent's sprite component and flips its y value as well. Let me know if this works, and if it does, please click 'accept' :)

Comment: @Sean...now i have the body rotating and flip instead of only flip when the arm go to the other side. Perhaps main body can't be parent of arm and have separate code?

see here: https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-480284950a10.gif

 void FlipMainBody(bool flip)
    {
        var pos = mainBody.localPosition;
        pos.y = Mathf.Abs(pos.y) * (flip ? -1 : 1);
        mainBody.localPosition = pos;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

@Sean, I separated the main_body from the arms and made a new script just for body rotation but now it happens to me this:

[My test char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUxma.gif)

The code:

```
void Update()
{
    Flip();
}

void Flip() 
{
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
    float WorldXPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos).x; 

    if (WorldXPos > gameObject.transform.position.x)
    {
        theScale.x = 1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
    else
    {
        theScale.x = -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}}
```

Almost there but not yet i need

Comment: Problem solved!! I adjust the player's and arm's sprites' origin point so that they fit properly and now both work fine. :)